# Can you prevent users from using same content in ask question wizard?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard

Some users are using the question wizard like this:

[image]

Which lead of question like that:

[image]

I saw multiple times question with this type of content, the same thing repeated- content copied from the details section and pasted into the "what did you try" section. In a few cases, the title is a little different.

Is that possible to add a check for this copy-paste behaviour that will result in a warning that asks for an edit before posting?

It would also help for the First Question review queue, and Staging Ground.

Comment: Are you sure this will actually improve things? To get to that point, the poster must already have disregarded quite a lot of advice. A warning can be ignored like all the other advice, and even preventing posting the question can easily be circumvented with padding.

Comment: :o In 5 minutes, it's in reviewing status

Comment: Getting status-review is the easy part. You now get to wait 6-8 for, most likely, nothing

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yes, it can. But without it's not possible to have upgrade of question. With it, it's possible to have at least a copy/paste of code, link or error

Comment: @MisterMiyagi IMO, we should still attempt to reduce this. The wizard should have far more safeguards in place to avoid stuff like this. The point isn't to be impenetrable, but to give so enough obstacles that exceptionally few make it past all of them. At least for the really obvious stuff, like section1 == section2. Right now, the wizard doesn't even try to improve post quality beyond the prompts.

Comment: It is the same as with multiplayer gaming servers. You don't implement measures to make it impossible to cheat, you implement barriers time consuming enough so the millions of people who want to cheat with next to zero effort give up. The few cheaters that do want to try hard can be banned when they are caught in the act, you just need to give players the proper tools to provide proof to speed up that process.

Comment: You often _can't_ make fully impenetrable measures. There are ways around any barrier with enough time and effort. The rest of what Gimby said is absolutely true though; the harder it is, the fewer people try, and those that do are far easier to handle (on account of there being less). Sadly, Stack's focus has not been on high-level moderation automation. There are many, many areas that would benefit from automatic quality checks (notably comments to tank "thanks" comments and encourage voting without needing extra noise to do so), but that don't have anything, and aren't getting it

Comment: I would be more for a minimal character count for the body to be honest. A question of one sentence is not a question that is worth having. That will also catch people just lazily copying the title. And that is very easily circumvented by just adding junk to the end of the question to pad it out... but that opens it up for site abuse flagging.

Comment: Yep, complete Support, such Qt's (Questions) are always VLQ, mostly by 1-Rep Users, ... who usually don't follow up / react to Comments at all... (One more [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75777852/3799241).) Some "basic" Checking on `Section_1 == Section_2` + `Char_Count > 100` (or 200?) would already prevent many of those VLQ Qt's. (+ Have to wait for 30 days before they will be roomba'd, grrr...!) And the Checks already exist, the Community Bot [is able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75777852#comment133676715_75777852) to detect those Posts...

Comment: @chivracq the check doesn't exists, the bot message comes from [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34061429). (I agree with this suggestion, maybe it will require another post)

Comment: Oh!, yep indeed, you're right...! Hum, me = Fool, thinking for a while the Community Bot could be that clever, oops...! (On a side-note, that Reviewer (5k-Rep) could also have edited the Qt, I would think...)

Comment: It's 2k rep for edit privilege, and even without this privileges you can see edit history. No user could change the community bot message

Comment: Yeah-yeah, I know that, but I mean that the Reviewer could also have directly edited the Question "a little bit", to remove the double Section, "*pest*" in the Title (instead of "*paste*") doesn't mean anything... But I guess the 'First Questions' Queue is so *depressing* that there is practically no/little use in trying to improve such Qt's if the Askers themselves don't want to put that effort...

Comment: [**How is questun wrote?** How is questun wrote How OP get ansurd? They need to do way instain mod> who close thier questuns.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll-lia-FEIY)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi before the Ask Question Wizard (2022) was introduced, they only had two opportunities to write the same text, instead of three. And honestly it feels like it was less common before, for people to duplicate title/body vs. now.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine pretty sure that getting status-review has taken years before.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Pushed a change adding validation into the ask wizard for these two sections to prevent folks from moving on with the same content in both boxes. This should be an easy win for cutting down on questions landing like the one in the screenshot above.

As mentioned in some comments above, the change isn't attempting to block all possible avenues but should help out in the common case where folks ignore the prompts and just copy/paste across inputs.

Comment: Ok thanks. Are further changes coming to prevent more specific as detecting new space or new char that could disable the alert?

Comment: The current implementation does at least trim whitespace before comparing. Ultimately the two sections get merged together on the UI so I'd _hope_ some # of folks realize why the two inputs shouldn't have the same content after they purposefully bypass the check and then end up with a single body input that has duplicate content. Aside from that, we're in early stages of broader improvements to question asking that we're hopeful and excited about but that will undoubtedly takeaway time and efforts on the more micro stuff.

Comment: As always thanks for the post here and please continue to feature req as you see fit - it really does help us prioritize and keep us accountable even if sometimes it takes longer than ideal.

Comment: yay! I have made so many edits before to remove duplicate text. glad this is done. I hope people don't just paste and add nonsense though (saying that even though I know it will probably happen at least once).

Comment: Note that it still appears to be possible to [put the same text in the title and one of the boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76006935).